# Birthday / congrats - plain integer 37 or ordinal 37th?

Tags: word-choice, numbers

Writing a birthday card to an important person, I want to write something like this:

> Congratulations on your 35-anniversary!...well, 37 tops ;-)

Should I use 37th instead of just 37?

Thanks a lot in advance!

P.S: The guy is actually turning 49, but looks really no older than 35))

Comment: You could drop the "th" in the 37 part: "Congratulations on your 35th birthday! Well, 37 [years old] max."

Comment: Thanks a lot, guys. Although, so attracted to that "tops" word. Totally not working in this sentence or could be left after all?

Comment: "tops" isn't so bad informally.

Comment: Great, so since it's a very informal message to this person, I am leaving it this way: Congratulations on your 35th birthday! ...well, 37 tops ;-)". Besides this all and some other pics will be placed not on an actual card it will be written on cupcakes with some illustrations and stuff. So, I guess it's rather informal, right?

Comment: Too late now, but i disagree with @WeatherVane.  I would include the 'th' in both instances and also change 'anniversary' to 'birhday'.  'Tops' is fine.

Comment: @mcalex so you agree with everything I said except 37.

Comment: Pretty much.  I didn't click that you'd put up both answer/comments.  I was disagreeing with the first one.

Answer (score 1):

For your birthday card

> Congratulations on your 35**th** birthday!...well, 37 tops.

I would add **th** to 37 since what you mean is

> Congratulations on your 35**th** Birthday!...well, 37**th** *Birthday* tops.

both 35**th** and 37**th** are adjectives for *birthday*.